# Trick Excel to believe a concatenated formula is really a formula to act upon

Tags: excel-formula

I am responsible for scheduling and I have 2 excel files (workbooks). One file is called “Schedule (2016)” and another file is called “My Schedule Assistant”.

The file or workbook “Schedule (2016)” is divided into multiple sheets for each pay period and lists all my people and where they will be assigned. The individual work sheets are pay period labeled (sheet tabs) as “PR#1 xxxx, PR#2 xxxx, PR#3 xxxx”, etc.

The purpose of the “My Schedule Assistant” is to help me to insure that I listed the employee on a particular day along with where they worked that entire pay period and then another section that will read from “Schedule (2016)” and tells me the assigned area and the employee that worked there. Sounds complicated, but really it is not.

In “My Schedule Assistant”, cells B3:B46 lists the employee’s call sign while cells D3:D46 lists their post assignments. Cells AA1:A022 lists the assignments and the employee that worked there. It obtains this information by reading one of the PR# worksheets and actually works great.

Currently I am only able to read from the specified “Schedule (2016)” worksheet by using the formula:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX('[Schedule (2016).xlsx]PR #26 DEC 25'!$C$4:$C$47,MATCH("WC",'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]PR #26 DEC 25'!$F$4:$F$47,0)),"None")
```

From time to time, however, I need to “My Schedule Assistant” to view another worksheet. Right now the only way I know how to do this is highlighting cells AA1:AO22 and use Excel’s find/replace function.

What I would like to do is to put the specified pay period date in a specific cell, let’s say I16 and have Excel use that desired pay period. I tried:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Schedule (2016).xlsx]I16'!$C$4:$C$47,MATCH("WC",'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]I16'!$F$4:$F$47,0)),"None")
```

. . . but this does not work. I also tried to be slick and concatenate this together in hopes of Excel treating this as a formula, but this doesn’t work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This solution provides the flexibility to choose from different `range` *targets* where to point the `formula`.

Assuming that there are 3 `range` targets (this can be extended to cover more ranges):

1. PR #26 DEC 25
2. I16
3. Any Other

Then in a cell above the header of your data *(using `B2` in this case)* add a `Data Validation` with the list of the target worksheets, i.e. *(see fig. 1 and 2)*:

`1. PR #26 DEC 25,2. I16,3. Any Other`

[image]
*Fig.1*

[image]
*Fig.2*

Then replace your formula with this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(
CHOOSE(LEFT($B$2,1),
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]PR #26 DEC 25'!$C$4:$C$47,
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]I16'!$C$4:$C$47,
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]Any Other'!$C$4:$C$47),
MATCH("WC",
CHOOSE(LEFT($B$2,1),
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]PR #26 DEC 25'!$F$4:$F$47,
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]I16'!$F$4:$F$47,
'[Schedule (2016).xlsx]Any Other'!$F$4:$F$47),0)),"None")
```

The formula above will use the range as indicated by your selection in cell `B2` (see fig.3)

[image]
*Fig.3*

Answer (score 0):

Would enclosing your formula in VALUE(.....) work?

Then you could also try
IFERROR(VALUE( ..... ),"Date Error")
then if it does error you have a specific message.
Best.